# What transformation(s) $g$ satisfy $\text{Cov}(g(X), g(Y)) \le c(g) \text{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Tags: random-variable, covariance

Given two random variables (say standard Normals) that are not necessarily independent, are there non-linear functions for which
$$
\text{Cov}(g(X), g(Y)) \le c(g) \text{Cov}(X,Y),
$$
where $c(g)$ is some constant that can depend on the function $g$. In other words, are there classes of functions $g$ that have covariance not too different from the covariance of the underlying variables?

**update**: Given the comments, my question is ill-posed, what I would like is an analog of Lipschitz continuity, so it should read that for **any** two gaussian random variables, the above bound holds, so the function $g$ can alter the covariance of the original variables by at most a fixed constant.

Comment: Your question asks for non-linear functions, so this is just a comment: covariance is invariant to translations by a constant.

Comment: A function $g$ that preserves covariance would satisfy $\operatorname{Cov}[g(X),g(Y)] = \operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]$, which not same at the inequality you give.

Comment: @Galen - 'preserve' was not a good word to describe what I mean, I've edited the question now

Comment: Is there any additional requirement on $c(g)$? It seems that since covariances are finite, you can surely find such an upper bound for any transformation.

Comment: @whoknowsnot you're right, I've added an edit to try to hopefully make the problem more well posed.

Comment: The answer is trivial: limit $g$ to functions with whichever property it is you desire (your question specifies two different ones).  That defines your "class of functions."  This shows the question is without any content, suggesting that maybe you haven't formulated the question you really want to ask.

Comment: @whuber, fair enough, I agree that I could have made things more clear - at the risk of changing the question after it has already been asked,  what I am trying to figure out is whether or not this property holds for interesting classes of functions - interesting here might mean differentiable, convex, lipschitz, smooth or some other class of functions that is commonly studied in the statistics literature

Comment: Again: *what* property are you referring to?  Your question appears to describe at least two (very) different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, as you say, standard Normal variates and $g(x) = x/10$ if $|x| < 100$, $0$ otherwise.  It should be intuitively obvious that the covariance between $g(x)$ and $g(y)$ is less than that of $x$ and $y$, so $c(g) = 1$ will do.

Clearly this approach is generalizable to other distributions; rescale the variables to be much smaller over the region where virtually all the probability mass lies, then impose some trivial nonlinearity in the region where there is essentially no probability mass.  The covariance of the transformed variables will (with a little care) be less than that of the original variables, so $c(g) = 1$ will do.